# Low audio output on Lenovo laptop

Tags: 18.04, sound, laptop, lenovo

My laptop's audio output is very low compared to Windows.
If the volume percentage is 22~ there is no sound.

I tried setting everything to max on alsamixer, but it does not make a difference. There was a mute channel, I did unmute it, but nothing...

This is my current alsamixer config:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjoI6.jpg

I've tried Debian and Linux Mint (Live USB): the problem still occurs.

Device: Lenovo Ideapad 320-15IKB
Ubuntu: 18.04.1 LTS

Launchpad bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1799998

Comment: Did you check the volume settings in the application that plays the sound?

Comment: @danzel it's not just one application. But yes, in my tests Spotify's volume was on max, so was YouTube's.

Comment: Same thing here with Lenovo Yoga S940
Also, microphone is not detected..

Comment: @DanieleDellafiore I added the link to the bug report, I think it would help if you mark it as "affects you".

Comment: I have the same issue with both my new Lenovo Laptop as well as my old HP laptop with Boom sound.

Comment: @Hauptideal I guess it would help if you commented on the bug report, since you have the issue in a different device

Comment: I don't know whether it really qualifies as a "bug", because it is to be expected that hardware does not run as well on generic linux drivers as on the manufacturer's device-specific ones. 
The same is true for battery life on Linux laptops etc. It's not a bug, it's just suboptimal hardware utilization.